# area HTML tag onCommand

Tags: asp.net

I have a map of america as a .gif image. I need to do a state selection on that image. In case of WA I define it as

```
<area href="#" runat="server" CommandArgument="WA"  OnCommand="StateClicked" coords="85,27,84,35,91,33,93,24,92,16,113,23,143,30,138,51,132,71,114,68,96,66,89,64,78,64,78,64,77,56,72,49,76,40,72,37,71,26,77,24" shape="POLY"/>
```

However, when I click on the WA state on the image, my following method doesn't get triggered.

```
protected void StateClicked(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Basically, I need to to a server side processing on the click of a state.

Comment: You should probably consider reimplementing this as an ASP [`ImageMap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ktz2hk4.aspx) with [`PolygonHotSpot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.polygonhotspot.aspx)s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack but you can fire events with hidden buttons for each area:

**Code-behind:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      areaWA.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.format("document.getElementById('{0}').click();", btnWA.ClientID))

  }

  protected void StateClicked(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
  {
     switch(e.CommandName)
     {
        case "StateClicked":               
           string arg = ((String)e.CommandArgument);
           break;

        default:
           //
           break; 
     }
  }
```

**Mark-up**

```
 <area href="#" id="areaWA" runat="server" coords="85,27,84,35,91,33,93,24,92,16,113,23,143,30,138,51,132,71,114,68,96,66,89,64,78,64,78,64,77,56,72,49,76,40,72,37,71,26,77,24" shape="POLY"/>

 <asp:Button id="btnWA"
           style="display:none"
           Text="whatever"
           CommandName="StateClicked"
           CommandArgument="WA"
           OnCommand="StateClicked" 
           runat="server"/>
```